# Transfer an amount between two ethereum accounts using json-rpc

Tags: transactions, json-rpc, nonce, wallet-transfer

I am trying to transfer some funds between 2 ethereum accounts of my own. I have a node and communicate with it using json-rpc protocol. I guess I need to use `eth_sendTransaction` method, but I find it quite confusing because data field is supposed to be filled with a smart contract, but I don't want to use any smart contract right now, just a simple transaction of a given amount between my ethereum accounts.

Do I have to call `eth_sendTransaction` method? How do I fill data field? What does nonce field is used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`eth_sendTransaction` can be used for sending Ether, for creating contracts and calling contract function. It all depends on the parameters.

1. For just sending Ether, you'd want to fill the `value`, `to` and `from` fields.
2. For creating contracts, you'd leave the `to` empty but fill in `data`.
3. For calling a contract function, you'd fill in both `to` and `data`, and optionally `value` if you also want to transfer Ether to the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [`eth_sendTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction)

> Creates new message call transaction or a contract creation, if the data field contains code.

1. `Object` - The transaction object

   - `from`: `DATA`, 20 Bytes - The address the transaction is send from.
   - `to`: `DATA`, 20 Bytes - (optional when creating new contract) The address the transaction is directed to.
   - `gas`: `QUANTITY`  - (optional, default: 90000) Integer of the gas provided for the transaction execution. It will return unused gas.
   - `gasPrice`: `QUANTITY`  - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) Integer of the gasPrice used for each paid gas
   - `value`: `QUANTITY`  - (optional) Integer of the value send with this transaction
   - `data`: `DATA`  - The compiled code of a contract OR the hash of the invoked method signature and encoded parameters. For details see [Ethereum Contract ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI)
   - `nonce`: `QUANTITY`  - (optional) Integer of a nonce. This allows to overwrite your own pending transactions that use the same nonce.

#### Example

```
params: [{
  "from": "0xb60e8dd61c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07233155",
  "to": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f07244567",
  "gas": "0x76c0", // 30400,
  "gasPrice": "0x9184e72a000", // 10000000000000
  "value": "0x9184e72a", // 2441406250
  "data": "0xd46e8dd67c5d32be8d46e8dd67c5d32be8058bb8eb970870f072445675058bb8eb970870f072445675"
}]
```